# Windows store app moves to not responding state after suspending

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

After suspending the windows store app, app goes to Not Responding state. I have tried this by suspending through VisualStudio and Windows OS suspend the app if the app is not used for sometime. but if we resume the app it is working correctly.

Any idea about why the app moves to Not responding state when suspending??

-Santyy

Comment: I think that the app can't store or restore the settings. Describe your app a bit more.

Comment: Just check your OnNavigatingFrom event. When app goes to suspend state it goes to OnNavigatingFrom event of the current page

Comment: What have you tried already? Does it break in Debugger? What is your code for restoring the state doing?